# NES (.NET Event Sourcing) running older NSB alright?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

We have an older installation running with NSB 2.0. I know NES is released for 2.5 but since it's just a layer on top I figure it should be possible to try NES with NSB 2.0. Also, for various reasons the customer does not want to upgrade NSB until it hits 3.0. So I'm evaluating using NES for this particular customer and it seems to compile and start up the samples alright.

But are there any compelling reasons not to use NES with NSB 2.0?

Werner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NES](http://getnes.net) will work fine with NSB 2.0+

Comment: Excellent. Thanks Elliot. I have tried but got an exception that is probably easily fixed. I can't paste exception details in a comment but I'll create another post for that.

Answer (score 0):

Event sourcing is just a pattern and it does not correlate with any particular messaging technology. NSB is hust a transport, you could even use some file-based message queues, RabbitMQ or Azure queues.